# Conditionally disable and input type button in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, button, razor, input

I have the following button:

```
<input type="button" id="btnNew" value="New Session" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("NewSession","Telesales")'" />
```

how can I disable the button when my `ViewBag` is not null?

I have tried the following but it does not seem to work on `input type button`

```
<input type="button" id="btnNew" value="New Session" @((ViewBag.Session != null) ? "disabled" : "true") onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("NewSession","Telesales")'" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like my solution was working the only problem was the default css with MVC3 was not changing for a disable button so the button was disabled but looked like a normal button. Added css to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use Jquery instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if('@ViewBag.Session' != null)
   {
     $("#btnNew").attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
});
```

----------------------------------------------Or try this----------------------------------

```
<input type="button" id="btnNew" value="New Session" @((ViewBag.Session != null) ? "disabled" : "") onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("NewSession","Telesales")'" />
```